# using jquery inside self invoke function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="inherit.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="observersContainer"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>


</html>
```

inherit.js

```
(function ($){
  $("#observersContainer").append( "<p>Test</p>" );
})(jQuery);
```

i am testing how to use self invoke function in my project and i was new to it , i try to use jquery inside my self invoke but noting happen , i added $ and pass the augment to the function , but still noting happen , so what i missed here ?

Comment: You are loading script in head. This will run IIFE before DOM is rendered. Put script tag at the end

Answer (score 0):

Replace the jquery import with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js> and change the code in inherit.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#observersContainer').append("<p>Test</p>");
});
```

That should do the job.